# angular2-cli include custom fonts

Tags: angular, fonts, webpack, angular2-cli

I am trying to include some custom fonts in my project with no success.

NOTE: I am using angular-cli: angular-cli@1.0.0-beta.21

1. I put the fonts in the folder

   src/assets/fonts/Roboto-Regular.tff
2. I add in `src/styles.css`

   ```
   @font-face {
     font-family: "Roboto-Regular";
     src: url("./assets/fonts/Roboto-Regular.tff");
   }
   ```
3. I use it in a component `.scss`

   ```
   font-family: "Roboto-Regular";
   ```
4. I get 404 error:

   ```
   Cannot find module "./assets/fonts/Roboto-Regular.tff"
   client?93b6:80 ./~/css-loader?sourcemap!./~/postcss-loader!./src/styles.css
   Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './assets/fonts/Roboto-Regular.tff' in 'D:\Work\Blah\angular\BlahFrontEnd\src'
   resolve './assets/fonts/Roboto-Regular.tff' in 'D:\Work\Blah\angular\BlahFrontEnd\src'
     using description file: D:\Work\Blah\angular\BlahFrontEnd\package.json (relative path: ./src)
       Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
     after using description file: D:\Work\Blah\angular\BlahFrontEnd\package.json (relative path: ./src)
       using description file: D:\Work\Blah\angular\BlahFrontEnd\package.json (relative path: ./src/assets/fonts/Roboto-Regular.tff)
         as directory
           D:\Work\Blah\angular\BlahFrontEnd\src\assets\fonts\Roboto-Regular.tff doesn't exist
         no extension
           Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
           D:\Work\Blah\angular\BlahFrontEnd\src\assets\fonts\Roboto-Regular.tff doesn't exist
         .ts
           Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
           D:\Work\Blah\angular\BlahFrontEnd\src\assets\fonts\Roboto-Regular.tff.ts doesn't exist
         .js
           Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
           D:\Work\Blah\angular\BlahFrontEnd\src\assets\fonts\Roboto-Regular.tff.js doesn't exist
   [D:\Work\Blah\angular\BlahFrontEnd\src\assets\fonts\Roboto-Regular.tff]
   [D:\Work\Blah\angular\BlahFrontEnd\src\assets\fonts\Roboto-Regular.tff]
   [D:\Work\Blah\angular\BlahFrontEnd\src\assets\fonts\Roboto-Regular.tff.ts]
   [D:\Work\Blah\angular\BlahFrontEnd\src\assets\fonts\Roboto-Regular.tff.js]
    @ ./~/css-loader?sourcemap!./~/postcss-loader!./src/styles.css 6:793-837
    @ ./src/styles.css
    @ multi styles
   ```

   5. If I add the font-face definition in `app.component.scss` I get 404 error as well

      ```
      jquery.js:2 GET http://localhost:4200/assets/fonts/Roboto-Regular.tff 404
      ```

Any ideas on how to include my Roboto-Regular.tff font?

Comment: Died you maybe mean ttf (TrueTypeFont) instead of tff?

Comment: you can include a font in your index.html 

 <link href=' http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Droid+Sans' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'

Comment: @Bernhard you are the man ... great spot :)

Answer (score 68, accepted):

For the people arriving here by searching:

Install with npm:

`npm install roboto-fontface --save`

Add to styles in `.angular-cli.json` (`apps[0].styles`):

```
"styles": [
    "styles.css",
    "../node_modules/roboto-fontface/css/roboto/roboto-fontface.css"
],
```

That's all!

Edit: since Angular 6 this file is called `angular.json` instead of `angular-cli.json`. Adding fonts still works the same way as before.

Comment: With a newly created project, one must add "../node_modules....." as the `root` is set to `src` by default. When doing this, building errors because the referenced font files cannot be found. How to do this with latest angular?

Comment: @ohcibi I checked and you are right. Updated the answer, thanks!

Comment: What if the npm package has no css/scss files?, just ttf.

Comment: This increases a build by 15 mb!

Comment: @RobinDijkhof The size increase has nothing to do with how it is implemented. The only thing this does is move an asset. So choose your assets wisely!

Comment: Instead of fiddling with `.angular-cli.json` on that matter I would rather do `@import '~roboto-fontface/css/roboto/roboto-fontface.css';` in `styles.scss`, this way it is more explicit

Comment: im completed all the above process , but the font is not changed , any other changes is there , like index.html files changes or something like that , pls help.

Answer (score 21):

Have you tried using the googlefont url from https://fonts.google.com?

In your styles.css:

```
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto');
```

Then use the font-family in styles.css or wherever you need:

```
body, html {
  font-family: 'Roboto';
}
```

I'm using this in my project and it works nicely.

Comment: Thee problem was misspelled name off the font

Comment: Not the best solution if you are doing a "stand-alone" which needs to be independent from the internet and has to work without any internet access. However works fine if your project is hosted online (and is actually better as many clients would have this font already cached because they have visited other sites which might have this font). :)

Answer (score 12):

If using SCSS you can:

Install `roboto-fontface`

```
npm install roboto-fontface --save
```

Import on your styles.scss file

```
@import '~roboto-fontface/css/roboto/roboto-fontface.css';

body {
  font-family: Roboto, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
}
```

Answer (score 7):

**This is best way to use google font locally with angular 2,4,5,6,7 and more**, First Download Google Font and this in inside the assets folder and use it is as per your requirement.

In angular.json call this in src/assets

```
"assets": [
    "src/assets"
 ],
```

In css file add this font-face in top

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Roboto';
  src: url(/assets/Roboto/Roboto-Regular.ttf) format("truetype");
  font-weight: 400;
}
```

At Last use it as per your requirement like

```
body{
 font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
}
```

Comment: This is the correct answer for me as my requirement is for an enterprise app that doesn't want to be pulling in remotely hosted fonts.

Comment: for downloading google fonts: https://google-webfonts-helper.herokuapp.com/fonts

Answer (score 3):

What you have done was correct, but with a small error:

```
@font-face { font-family: "Roboto-Regular"; src: url("./assets/fonts/Roboto-Regular.tff"); }
```

You have given `tff` instead of `ttf`

Try this :

```
@font-face { font-family: "Roboto-Regular"; src: url("./assets/fonts/Roboto-Regular.ttf"); }
```

Comment: Someone had mentioned that in the comments on the post