# Using Fonts in SCSS with Webpack 4

Tags: angular, webpack

I have an Angular 6 SPA with Webpack 4 for bundling based on the following repo;

[AngularWebpackVisualStudio Example Repo](https://github.com/damienbod/AngularWebpackVisualStudio)

However, I am having issue with importing external fonts to the project. From looking at the `webpack.dev.config.js` I have the following code;

```
{
     test: /\.(png|jpg|gif|woff|woff2|ttf|svg|eot)$/,
     use: 'file-loader?name=assets/[name]-[hash:6].[ext]'
}
```

Which should bundle the fonts. I have a `.ttf` file located in my angular app folder ( `/ClientApp/fonts/Font.ttf`);

then in my `app.component.scss` I have tried adding the following;

```
@import '../fonts/Font.ttf';

@font-face {
    font-family: MyFont;
    src: url("../fonts/Font.ttf") format("opentype");
}
```

However, when I then run the site I am getting a 404 error on the font file? 
`localhost/fonts/Font.tff`

Could someone please direct me as to what I am doing wrong here please?

Answer (score 0):

Add the fonts to `angular.json` under `styles`:

[angular2-cli include custom fonts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40884511/angular2-cli-include-custom-fonts)